# how the map container M.end() work in this code ? is it return the last vaue of map

Tags: c++11, dictionary

```
 map < string , int > M;

 M["Top"] = 1; 

 M["Coder"] = 2; 

 M["SRM"] = 10; 

 int x = M["Top"] + M["Coder"]; 

 if(M.find("SRM") != M.end()) { 

      M.erase(M.find("SRM")); // or even M.erase("SRM") 
 }
```

Comment: Please format your code properly, add a question to the body and appropriate tags

Comment: `M.end()` returns an iterator, not a value. I'm not sure I quite understand the question.

Comment: Welcome to topcoder. M.end() point to the element behind the last element of the map, if you want to get the last pointer of the map, --M.end()  can do that

Comment: @kaitian I'd prefer `M.rbegin()` over `--M.end()` any time, though ;-)

Comment: Yes！ you are right. I made a mistake for some years

Answer (score 2):

If no element is found in the M, find() returns M.end(). M.end() points to the element following the last element of the container, it is a 
boundary iterator (no data is at this position).

See:

http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find
http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/end

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine, when the string "SRM" is found in the map, it will be erased from it. Because when method find() does not finds the value it returns an iterator pointing to the end of container.
Maybe you could reformulate question, to be more precise what you want to achieve.